# How to use NNLS for non-negative multiple linear regression?

Tags: java, apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to solve Non-negative multiple linear regression problem in Java. 
And I found a solver class [`org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.NNLS`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLS.html) written in Scala. 
However, I don't know how to use this.

What makes me confused is that the interface of the following method seems strange.
I thought that `A` is a MxN matrix and `b` is a M-vector, and the arguments `ata` and `atb` should be a NxN matrix and N-vector, respectively.
However, the actual type of `ata` is `double[]`.

```java
public static double[] solve(double[] ata, double[] atb, NNLS.Workspace ws)
```

I searched for an example code but I couldn't find.
Can anyone give me a sample code?
The library is written in Scala, but I want Java code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** I've never used `NNLS` and got no idea about non-negative multiple linear regression.

You look at Spark 2.1.1's `NNLS` that does what you want, but is not the way to go since [the latest Spark 2.2.1 marked as private[spark]](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLS.scala#L28).

```
private[spark] object NNLS {
```

More importantly, as of Spark 2.0, `org.apache.spark.mllib` package (incl. `org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization` that `NNLS` belongs to) is in [maintenance mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api):

> The MLlib RDD-based API is now in maintenance mode.
>
> As of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the spark.mllib package have entered maintenance mode. The primary Machine Learning API for Spark is now the DataFrame-based API in the spark.ml package.

In other words, you should stay away from the package and `NNLS` in particular.

What are the alternatives then?

You could look at the tests of `NNLS`, i.e. [NNLSSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLSSuite.scala#L27) where you could find some answers.

> However, the actual type of ata is double[].

That's a matrix so elements are doubles again. As a matter of fact, `ata` is passed directly to BLAS's `dgemv` ([here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLS.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L106) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLS.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L79)) that is described in the [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_gadd421a107a488d524859b4a64c1901a9.html#gadd421a107a488d524859b4a64c1901a9) docs:

> DGEMV  performs one of the matrix-vector operations
>
> ```
> y := alpha*A*x + beta*y,   or   y := alpha*A**T*x + beta*y,
> ```
>
> where alpha and beta are scalars, x and y are vectors and A is an
>    m by n matrix.

That should give you enough answers.

---

Another question would be what the recommended way in Spark MLlib for `NNLS`-like computations is?

It looks like Spark MLLib's ALS algorithm [uses](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L787) `NNLS` under the covers (which may not be that surprising for machine learning practitioners).

That part of the code is used when ALS is configured to train a model with [nonnegative](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L198-L204) parameter turned on, i.e. `true` (which is disabled by default).

> **nonnegative** Param for whether to apply nonnegativity constraints.
>
> Default: false
>
> whether to use nonnegative constraint for least squares

I would recommend reviewing that part of Spark MLlib to get deeper into the uses of `NNLS` for solving non-negative linear regression problem.

Comment: Thank you for detailed description. 

`In other words, you should stay away from the package and NNLS in particular.`

So, shouldn't I use NNLS at the moment?
Anyway, I read [NNLSSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/NNLSSuite.scala#L27) and found that `ata` is flattened. I wrote some test codes and it seems to work well. So I will post it bellow.

Comment: _"So, shouldn't I use NNLS at the moment?"_ that seems so. Accept the answer (or upvote at the very least) if it helped. That will help others to find what helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test code.
Though I got some warnings like `Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS`, it works well for simple cases, but `beta` often becomes 0 when `m` is very large (about 3000).

```java
package test;

import org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.NNLS;

public class NNLSTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6, m = 300;
        ExampleInMatLabDoc();
        AllPositiveBetaNoiseInY(n, m);
        SomeNegativesInBeta(n, m);
        NoCorrelation(n, m);
    }

    private static void test(double[][] X, double[] y, double[] b) {        
        int m = X.length; int n = X[0].length;

        double[] Xty = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Xty[i] = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) Xty[i] += X[j][i] * y[j];
        }
        double[] XtX = new double[n * n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                XtX[n * i + j] = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) XtX[n * i + j] += X[k][i] * X[k][j];
            }
        }

        double[] beta = NNLS.solve(XtX, Xty, NNLS.createWorkspace(n));
        System.out.println("\ntrue beta\tbeta");
        for (int i = 0; i < beta.length; i++) System.out.println(b[i] + "\t" + beta[i]);

    }

    private static void ExampleInMatLabDoc() {
        // https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqnonneg.html
        double[] y = new double[] { 0.8587, 0.1781, 0.0747, 0.8405 };
        double[][] x = new double[4][];
        x[0] = new double[] { 0.0372, 0.2869 };
        x[1] = new double[] { 0.6861, 0.7071 };
        x[2] = new double[] { 0.6233, 0.6245 };
        x[3] = new double[] { 0.6344, 0.6170 };
        double[] b = new double[] { 0.0, 0.6929 };
        test(x, y, b);
    }

    private static void AllPositiveBetaNoiseInY(int n, int m) {
        double[] b = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[i] = Math.random() * 100.0;       // random value in [0:100]
        double[] y = new double[m];
        double[][] x = new double[m][];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            x[i] = new double[n];
            x[i][0] = 1.0;
            y[i] = b[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                x[i][j] = (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 100.0; // random value in [-100:100]
                y[i] += x[i][j] * b[j];
            }
            y[i] *= 1.0 + (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 0.1; // add noise
        }
        test(x, y, b);
    }

    private static void SomeNegativesInBeta(int n, int m) {
        double[] b = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[i] = (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 100.0; // random value in [-100:100]
        double[] y = new double[m];
        double[][] x = new double[m][];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            x[i] = new double[n];
            x[i][0] = 1.0;
            y[i] = b[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                x[i][j] = (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 100.0; // random value in [-100:100]
                y[i] += x[i][j] * b[j];
            }
        }
        test(x, y, b);
    }

    private static void NoCorrelation(int n, int m) {
        double[] y = new double[m];
        double[][] x = new double[m][];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            x[i] = new double[n];
            x[i][0] = 1.0;
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) 
                x[i][j] = (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 100.0; // random value in [-100:100]
            y[i] = (2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0) * 100.0;
        }
        double[] b = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[i] = 0;
        test(x, y, b);
    }
}
```